# how to send sms to using perl?

Tags: perl, perl-module

Tried below simple ones

code1 using [`Net::SMS::WAY2SMS`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aSMS%3a%3aWAY2SMS)

```
use strict;   
use warnings;  
use Net::SMS::WAY2SMS;

my $sms = Net::SMS::WAY2SMS->new(  
'user' => 'user_name' ,  
'password' => 'secret_password',  
'mob' => ['1234567890', '0987654321']
);

# multi line sms
$sms->send(q[testing
sending
sms]);
#end1
```

No error displayed and not working

code2 using [`Net::SMS::160By2`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aSMS%3a:160By2)

```
#!C:/strawberry/perl/bin/perl.exe
use strict;  
use warnings;  
use Net::SMS::160By2;
my $username = "9823763544";  
my $password = "sssssss";  
my $msg = "Hi";  
my $to = "9922334455";  
my $obj = Net::SMS::160By2->new($username, $password);  
$obj->send_sms($msg, $to);  
#end2
```

Error:can't call method "action" on undefined values at C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/net/SMS/160By2.pm at line 196.

I have also tried several other scripts and none of them worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why `Net::SMS::WAY2SMS` is not working is the issue with module. There is no standard API being provided by Way2SMS team, and they keep changing their interface. That is why all the Android apps related to Way2SMS also stop working after a month or two (as soon as Way2SMS team changes interface). As long as Way2SMS doesn't provide an API, you'll not get a stable solution.

Same issue with 160By2.

Line 196 of 160By2.pm is `$form->action($sendsms_submit_uri);` and the error you get is `can't call method "action" on undefined values`. That means `$form` is undefined.

In module author has used `our $SENDSMS_URL = 'http://160by2.com/FebSendSMS';`

`$mech` here is trying to get the above URL.

```
my $sendsms_uri = URI->new($SENDSMS_URL);
$mech->get($sendsms_uri->as_string);`
```

and then at the end it does

`my $form = $mech->form_name('frm_sendsms');` and

`$form->action($sendsms_submit_uri);`

But if you notice the **`$SENDSMS_URL` gives `404` error (This URL doesn't even exist)**. Hence it gives error.

Comment: I visited the site and no renaming of the form is done. it is named 'frm_sendsms'. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Look at [SMS::Send](http://metacpan.org/release/SMS-Send) - it provides a sane interface to various SMS::Send::* drivers for various SMS-sending facilities - so you can change providers easily without major changes to your code.

I personally use AQL (www.aql.com) via SMS::Send::AQL - they're a UK-based company, though, so may not be very useful for you if you're outside the UK.

If you can't find an SMS::Send::* driver for a service you wish to use, you could write and release your own.

Answer (score -1):

There is a `smscmd1` sample can be referred. It is called by using PERL system
Syntax :

```
 system("./smscmd1", "$ARGV[0]","$ARGV[1]","$ARGV[3]","$ARGV[4]")
```

Refer http://www.sms4mail.com/smsmail/smscmd.htm for more details.